# I would like to make simple click speed test in Python (tkinter) but I have problems with buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, time, timer

I would like to make simple click speed test in Python (tkinter).My actual code looks like that:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def coutdown():
    t = 5
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
        if t==0:
            print("Finish !!!")
            break

#window configuration
screen= Tk()
screen.title("Click Speed Test")
screen.configure(width= 500, height= 300)
screen.configure(bg='lightblue')
canvas = Canvas(screen, width=500, height=500)

#text
text= Label(screen, text= "Click Speed Test")
text.config(font= ("Courier", 16))
text.pack()
text_v2= Label(screen, text= "Click the button to start the game!")
text_v2.config(font= ("Courier", 10))
text_v2.pack(ipady= 10)

# start button
turn_on= Button(screen, text="Start", command= coutdown)
turn_on.pack(ipadx=10, ipady= 5, pady= 5, padx= 100)

#click button
click= Button(screen, text="Click!!!")
click.pack(ipadx=6, ipady= 8, pady= 5, padx= 5)

screen.mainloop()
```

I have big problem with buttons. I made fuction: coutdown, which is to calculate time and I set it as a command to start button. Second button will be use to click on it after start the game, but now it hasn't a command. My vision look like that: When I will start the game by "Start" button, I will have 5 seconds to click "Click" button as many as I can. After 5 seconds script will shut down and and the result will display. But now if I click start button, all script freezes and I can't click any button. Do you know how to fix it?

I tried to change my timer but all the time script works wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

num = 0
tm = 0

def count():
    global num
    if tm:
        num += 1

def coutdown():
    global tm
    tm = time.time()

def refresh():
    global tm, num
    dif = time.time() - tm
    if tm and dif > 5:
        print("Finish !!!", num, 'clicks')
        num = 0
        tm = 0
    elif tm:
        mins, secs = divmod(int(dif), 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
    screen.after(1, refresh)      
        
#window configuration
screen= Tk()
screen.title("Click Speed Test")
screen.configure(width= 500, height= 300)
screen.configure(bg='lightblue')
canvas = Canvas(screen, width=500, height=500)

#text
text= Label(screen, text= "Click Speed Test")
text.config(font= ("Courier", 16))
text.pack()
text_v2= Label(screen, text= "Click the button to start the game!")
text_v2.config(font= ("Courier", 10))
text_v2.pack(ipady= 10)

# start button
turn_on= Button(screen, text="Start", command= coutdown)
turn_on.pack(ipadx=10, ipady= 5, pady= 5, padx= 100)

#click button
click= Button(screen, text="Click!!!", command= count)
click.pack(ipadx=6, ipady= 8, pady= 5, padx= 5)

#screen.mainloop()
refresh_var = screen.after_idle(refresh)
mainloop()
```